# TranslateTransform with slider binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, slider

Can't understand why `Translatetransform` binding isn't working. I have 3 sliders - one for scaling, and 2 for x and y transforming (I have circles as child elements of `Canvas` in code).

I am using below XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Visualizer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="MainCanvas" >
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="OperatorsCanvas" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="OperatorsContent"/>
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform 
                    CenterX="0" 
                    CenterY="0"
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
                    />
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=TranslateXSlider,Path=Value}" Y="{Binding ElementName=TranslateYSlider,Path=Value}" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        </Canvas>
        <Slider Canvas.Right="5" Width="154" Canvas.Top="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="ScaleSlider" ToolTip="Determines the UI scale factor."
                    Value="1" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="4"/>
        <Slider Canvas.Bottom="0" Width="762"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="TranslateXSlider" Value="0" Minimum="-20" Maximum="20"/>
        <Slider Canvas.Right="0" Canvas.Top="282" Width="423" RenderTransformOrigin="0.494,0.455" Height="16" Name="TranslateYSlider"  Value="0" Minimum="-20" Maximum="20" >
            <Slider.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Slider.RenderTransform>
        </Slider>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Scaling works but transform doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Translations in `LayoutTransform` are ignored, as explained in the Remarks section in the [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) documentation on MSDN. You will have to replace `LayoutTransform` by `RenderTransform` in order to make it work:

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform
                ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ScaleSlider,Path=Value}"/>
            <TranslateTransform
                X="{Binding ElementName=TranslateXSlider,Path=Value}"
                Y="{Binding ElementName=TranslateYSlider,Path=Value}"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

---

Please also note that Slider has an [`Orientation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.orientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Hence there is no need to apply a transform there.